# Detect consecutive objects with a common attribute in 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have a 2-D array of gems, all the gems have been given random color. Now i want to detect if three or more consecutive gems in a row or column has the same color. If so i want to do some action with those gems.

```
Gem gems[10][10];

for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<10;++j){
        gems[i][j].setColor(GetRandInRange(0,6));   
    }
}
bool detectMatch(){
  for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<10;++j){
        // Code to detect three or more consecutive gems with same color
        // Give some special color to the matched gems
    }
}
```

Here is how i tried but it doesn't work

```
  bool GameBoard::findMatch(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<10;++j){
            if(j!=0){  
            if(gems[i][j].getColor()==gems[i][j-1].getColor()){ //Color same with previous one
                int a=i, b=j;
                while(gems[a][b].getColor()==gems[i][j].getColor() && (a<10 && b<10)){ // Check till the color does not match
                    count++;
                    a++;
                    b++;
                }
                if(count>=3){  //If 3 or more have matched
                    for(int a=i, b=j, c=0;c<count;++c){
                      gems[a][b].setColor(0);       
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

if you can help me with this code please

Comment: There are a few questions tat is not clear: The array is limited to 10 by 10? Or can be larger? If you find three consecutive gems in a row has the same color, and if there are gems in above row or lower row adjacent to the gems you find, do you need change color of these gems as well?

Comment: @TigerYu I want it to change the color of first match detected, because it is called in a do while loop in main program, until it returns false.

Comment: and ya the array size is limited to 10 by 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it. You need to do two scans. First, you need to scan for runs in one direction, then the other. It's much simpler than trying to loop through once.

I first check for horizontal runs, exiting as soon as one longer than 2 is found. Same with the vertical ones. Your function has a bool signature, so I've assumed you'll use another function to determine the location of the run - you could easily return a struct that held the position, direction and length from the findMatch method.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

var gems;

function onLoaded(evt) {
  // create and initialize the array
  gems = new Array();
  for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    let curRow = new Array();
    for (var col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
      let curCell = new Gem();
      curCell.setColor(GetRandInRange(0, 6));
      curRow.push(curCell);
    }
    gems.push(curRow);
  }

  // display it for the user
  displayGems();

  // check if there's 3 or more in a vertical or horizontal line.
  console.log(hasMatch());
}

class Gem {
  setColor(colIndex) {
    this.color = colIndex;
  }
  getColor() {
    return this.color;
  }
};

function displayGems() {
  var str = '';
  for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    if (row != 0)
      str += "\n";

    var dat = gems[row];

    dat.forEach((gem, idx) => {
      if (idx != 0)
        str += ', ';
      str += gem.getColor();
    });
  }
  console.log(str);
}

function GetRandInRange(lower, upper) {
  return ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower + 0.5) >> 0;
}

function hasMatch() {
  let matchFound = 0;

  // scan #1 - horizontally on each row
  for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    let last = undefined;
    let runLength = 0;
    for (var col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
      let cur = gems[row][col].getColor();
      if (cur == last) {
        runLength++
        if (runLength > 2) {
          console.log(`horiz - ${row+1}`);
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        runLength = 0;
        last = cur;
      }
    }
  }

  for (var col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
    let last = undefined;
    let runLength = 1;
    for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
      let cur = gems[row][col].getColor();
      if (cur == last) {
        runLength++;
        if (runLength > 2) {
          console.log(`vert - ${col+1}`);
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        runLength = 1;
        last = cur;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```